# Disable back and recent keys while gaming

Tags: root-access, google-play-games, softkey

The title speaks of itself, I keep pressing them by mistake and lose my games progress , is there anything like Samsung game launcher to disable those keys? (I can't install game launcher for some reason)
My device is Samsung Galaxy J7 core and I have root privileges with magisk installed (and automagic if there's some automation trick)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

I found a solution, by using Automagic and Tasker Autoinput plugin we can easily Remap everything in the screen.
In the flow below , when a game (brawl stars) starts then do the below actions (disable keys, display ongoing notification to enable keys whenever I want, and a toast)[image]